# Built-in PDF viewer libraries or APIs for asp.net that block download

Tags: pdf, embed, pdf-viewer

I need a library or PDF viewer API that blocks user downloads, but is minimally customizable, so that I can use zoom and rotation, for example

The default browser embed does not block satisfactorily as the context menu is not tractable. I tried the Adobe Embed API, and it almost solved my problem, all that was missing was the possibility to rotate the pages, something that the client does not give up.